# codeigniter url base path not working/prepending

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, base-url

Hey so I am developing locally in Codeigniter and my project folder is:

```
http://localhost/feeder_final/
```

When I do anything like:

```
header('Location: /site_client/dashboard');
```

or click on an href='/site_client/' 
It redirects to:

```
http://localhost/site_client/
```

Not:

```
http://localhost/feeder_final/site_client/
```

I feel like I have tried everything... base_url, htaccess, etc,

But I just can't get it to work.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tried `base_url`, did you put brackets afterwards? `base_url()` is a function so it needs brackets. See the [Codeigniter manual](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html). This should work:

```
header('Location: '.base_url().'site_client/dashboard/');
```

or

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>site_client">site client</a>
```

Comment: I agree with GluePear. If you set your `base_url` in your config, then you should use it this way.

Comment: thanks a lot, I don't know why, but I thought there was a way to get around adding 'base_url()' to every url, I guess not. We haven't needed it before as we haven't been developing locally, only on a dev site, and there was not any base besides the host.

Answer (score 1):

Use base_url() for HTML assests like: Image, js & css, eg:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js/jquery.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Use site_url() for links, eg:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function'); ?>">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use base_url()  or site_url()  in case you will change your domain in the future.

Btw. you can also use site_url('controller/method')  same for redirection =>  redirect('controller/method')